# scope of references to external smart contract, global variables, eleminiate redundant code

Tags: solidity, contract-design, external-api, scope

Imagine that there's a smart contract deployed which contains a number of sub-contracts like so:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract A {
   address contract = 0x6663130dDfF21E3BC963Ee902005223b9A202106;
   ...
   contract.doSomething()
}

contract B {
   address contract = 0x6663130dDfF21E3BC963Ee902005223b9A202106;
   ...
   contract.doSomethingElse()
}
```

Is it possible to extract the reference that both of them make to the same external contract so as not to duplicate the same code?

For example something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

address contract = 0x6663130dDfF21E3BC963Ee902005223b9A202106;

contract A {
   ...
   contract.doSomething()
}

contract B {
   ...
   contract.doSomethingElse()
}
```

Is that valid?

**UPDATE**

```
contract Fruit {
    address thing = address(12345);
}

contract Apple is Fruit {
    function eat() external {
        thing.call("");
    }
}

contract Banana is Fruit {
    function eat() external {
        thing.call("");
    }
}
```

^is there a way to prove definitively that this uses less gas?